# Mysql duplicated id

Tags: mysql, database, join

I need to take some data from database, but select sometimes duplicate id. This problem is because of inner join but I cannot solve it.
The problem exists only when the product has more than one image.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ps_product_lang.id_product as id_product,
    ps_product_lang.name as title_product,
    ps_product_lang.description as product_description,
    ps_image.id_image as id_image
FROM
    ps_product_lang
INNER JOIN ps_image
    ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_image.id_product
ORDER BY ps_product_lang.id_product ASC
```

Comment: Try adding a GROUP BY to this. Sometimes, using DISTINCT isn't enough.

Comment: A join with an 1:n relationship shows these n rows, so add GROUP BY and add aggregation functions for the parts thta not repeat.

Comment: after group by im getting this error: Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'prestashop.ps_product_lang.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: It is enough to use this query: SET @@sql_mode = ''; to solve problem above but is there any another solution? without changing sql_mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have multiple matching in your JOIN, you receive multiple rows for each record in `ps_product_lang` table.

As You want to get one row per `ps_product_lang` you must decide how to aggregate date from `ps_image` table.
For example you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` method with `GROUP BY`. So you query can look as next:

```
SELECT
    ps_product_lang.id_product as id_product,
    ps_product_lang.name as title_product,
    ps_product_lang.description as product_description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ps_image.id_image) as id_images
FROM
    ps_product_lang
INNER JOIN ps_image
    ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_image.id_product
GROUP BY 
    -- all not aggregated field must be appears here
    ps_product_lang.id_product,
    ps_product_lang.name,
    ps_product_lang.description
ORDER BY ps_product_lang.id_product ASC;
```

Another way is join already aggregated table:

```
SELECT
    ps_product_lang.id_product as id_product,
    ps_product_lang.name as title_product,
    ps_product_lang.description as product_description,
    groupped_images.id_images
FROM
    ps_product_lang
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        id_product,
        GROUP_CONCAT(ps_image.id_image) AS id_images
    FROM ps_image
    GROUP BY ps_image.id_product
) groupped_images
    ON ps_product_lang.id_product = groupped_images.id_product
ORDER BY ps_product_lang.id_product ASC;
```

In both cases you not need to use `DISTINCT` keyword. The rows uniqueness solved by right grouping. The `GROUP_CONCAT` operator can be changed by another [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html):